# Local-to-Global Spectral Sequence for locally free resolution

Tags: sheaf-cohomology, spectral-sequences, coherent-sheaves

Consider two coherent sheaves $\mathcal{E},\mathcal{F}$, with locally free resolutions
\begin{align}
&0 \longrightarrow \mathcal{E}_1 \longrightarrow \cdots \longrightarrow \mathcal{E}_n \longrightarrow \mathcal{E} \longrightarrow 0 \\
&0 \longrightarrow \mathcal{F}_1 \longrightarrow \cdots \longrightarrow \mathcal{F}_n \longrightarrow \mathcal{F} \longrightarrow 0.
\end{align}
The Ext-groups can be computed via the spectral sequence
\begin{align}
E_2^{pq} \equiv H^p(X, \mathcal{Ext}^q(\mathcal{E}, \mathcal{F})) \Rightarrow \mathrm{Ext}^{p+q}(\mathcal{E},\mathcal{F}),
\end{align}
and in turn the $\mathcal{Ext}$-sheaves can be related to the locally free resolution of$\mathcal{E}$ by
\begin{align}
\mathcal{Ext}^i (\mathcal{E}, \mathcal{F}) = H^i( \mathcal{Hom}(\mathcal{E}_\bullet, \mathcal{F}).
\end{align}
My question is: Is there any way, I can also express the last equation in terms of the locally free resolution of $\mathcal{F}$ at the same time?

Thanks in advance!